# Valores nulos en ActionResult ASP netcore MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropdownlist

Estoy tratando de conseguir los valores de un dropdownlist, primero le paso los datos desde una base de datos, lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione una opcion de la lista me devuela la demas informacion desde la base de datos, pero al pasar el valor de id siempre me retorna un valor nulo.

Este es mi controlador

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Pedido.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Create()
{    
    var lista = new Producto();    
    lista.Listasnom = db.Producto.ToList();

    return View(lista);
}  

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Producto producto)
{    
    var lista = new Producto();     
    lista.Listasnom = db.Producto.ToList();

    var emp = lista.Listasnom.Where(e => e.Id == producto.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    lista.Id = emp.Id;
    lista.Nombre = emp.Nombre; 
    lista.Precio = emp.Precio;

    return View(lista);
}
```

Mi modelo

```
public partial class Producto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Precio { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List <Producto> Listasnom { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable < SelectListItem > ProductoListItems  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return new SelectList(Listasnom, "Id", "Nombre"); 
        }  
    }
}
```

Y mi vista, en donde paso los valores de la base de datos con un dropdownlist y desde ahi consigo el valor del id para devolverlo a mi action

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Pedido", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "demoForm", name = "demoForm" }))  
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.ProductoListItems, "Elegir Producto", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })

    <br>
        <fieldset>  
            <legend>Producto Seleccionado</legend>  
            <div class="display-label">  
                <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id) </strong>  
            </div>  
            <div class="display-field">  
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)  
            </div>  
            <div class="display-label">  
                <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre) </strong>  
            </div>  
            <div class="display-field">  
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre)  
            </div>  
            <div class="display-label">  
                <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio) </strong>  
            </div>  
            <div class="display-field">  
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Precio)  
            </div>  
        </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">  
function SelectedIndexChanged() {  
    //Form post  
    document.demoForm.submit();  
}  
</script>
```

Cuando realizo el selectedindexchanged el error me lo tira en mi lista enumerable

```
public IEnumerable < SelectListItem > ProductoListItems  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return new SelectList(Listasnom, "Id", "Nombre"); 
    }  
}
```

error:
[image: error lanzado]

Comment: Hola, podrías indicar en el código la directiva **@model ...** que tienes en la Vista?.

Comment: @model punto.Models.Producto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes cuando realizas el **Submit**, ya que el campo **`Producto.Listasnom`** te está llegando a **NULL**.

Eso es lógico, ya que desde la Vista solo estás enviando el valor del **Id** a la Acción `Create()`, el resto de las propiedades del Modelo llegan a **NULL o vacías**.

Lo que debes hacer es **comprobar** si **`Producto.Listasnom`** es **NULL**, y si es así, sustituirlo por una nueva instancia de `List<Producto>()`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductoListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(Listasnom ?? new List<Producto>(), "Id", "Nombre");                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow hermano exactamente ese era el problema eres un crack! Habia pasado mas de 10 horas tratando de solucionarlo muchas gracias!

Comment: @Aux1234 Estupendo! me alegro. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han servido para solucionar tu pregunta.